# NPM: The "ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5" on On OS X El Capitan?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, node-gyp

When I use `npm install` to install dependencies of [this repository](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-webpack-example), I encountered an error like this:

```
> fsevents@0.3.8 install /Users/hanfeisun/Workspace/vue-webpack-example/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/hanfeisun/Workspace/vue-webpack-example/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.8
```

However, the installation is still finished successfully. And when I use `npm run`, the app still works well. Does anyone have ideas about what `node-gyp rebuild` does here? And why the project works well even `node-gyp` throws error here?

Comment: The last line gives away why it still works, it's an optional dependency

Comment: c.f. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved after I reinstalled node.js from the official pkg.

Answer (score 63):

I ran into this problem after upgrading to Node 4.1.0 (OS X 10.10.5) and didn't have any luck after reinstalling from the official package. For what it's worth, this solved it for me:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
```

(Originally found [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40653).)

Comment: Just wanted to note that this solved my issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Works in OS X 10.11.1 too

Comment: Works in OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. Turns out I had upgraded Xcode but never rebooted. After reboot I was able to `npm install` successfully.