# node-gyp : ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5

Tags: node.js, xcode

I am trying to install node-gyp, and I have this error :

I am using XCode 7.1, I tried to downgrade my version of NodeJS but it doesn't work.

I have been looking over on the internet for solutions but I cannot find any.

```
npm WARN package.json myk@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json myk@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json myk@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN package.json Dependency 'gulp' exists in both dependencies and devDependencies, using 'gulp@^3.5.6' from dependencies

contextify@0.1.14 install /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MYKapp/MYK/ionic/MYK/node_modules/gulp-dom/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/contextify.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/contextify.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MYKapp/MYK/ionic/MYK/node_modules/gulp-dom/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! contextify@0.1.14 install: node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.14 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MYKapp/MYK/ionic/MYK/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ npm-check-updates -u
$ npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and what worked for Emmanuel didn't work for me. In the end, this solved my problem:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
```

Originally found [under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32654062/1270459)